# Not getting desired refresh rate when using SetPresentDuration method

Tags: c++, directx, win32com, dxgi, d3dx

I want to set a custom refresh rate in my DX application for that I have used `SetPresentDuration()` method of `IDXGISwapChainMedia` interface, the method is returning `S_OK` but when I am checking the refresh rate it is not setting up as expected. Do I need to set some specific value in the `flag` member of `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC` structure as we need `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH` value in the flag if we use `ResizeTarget()` method for setting custom refresh rate.

```
hr = scMedia->SetPresentDuration ((UINT)500000); //20Hz
```

`scMedia` is a pointer of the type `IDXGISwapChainMedia`. `S_OK` is coming in `hr` which means this refresh rate has been set but in actual it's not.

Comment: Perhaps you need to invoke `CheckPresentDurationSupport` to figure out whether this custom duration is actually supported.

Comment: I did that, it also returned `S_OK`